# How do I output my toString method to a dialog box in main?

Tags: java

```
public String toString()
      {
       String message "sadsd: " + aaa + "\nfsdfds: " + bbb;
       return message;
       }
     }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message.toString());
}
```

I have a class that has a toString method to display the instance variables of an object and in another class I have the main to display the output. How come it doesn't return the message to main

Comment: `In another class?` then you need to instantiate that class and not just call message.something. What's `message`?

Comment: Well, you say it, you have “… a toString method to display the *instance variables of an object*”. But you never create an instance of your class.

Comment: is `message` the instance of the class tat has overriden the `toString` method?

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo. Should be `String message = ....` You didn't have the `=`.
Full working example:

Have one class Message.java

```
public class Message {
    String aaa;
    String bbb;

    public Message() {
        aaa = "Hey";
        bbb = "This is a test";
    }

    public String toString() {
        String message = "sadsd: " + aaa + "\nfsdfds: " + bbb;
        return message;
    }
}
```

Then you have another class, for instance AnotherClass.java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class AnotherClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Message message = new Message();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that a simple typo? That's a whole new class to be added

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I don't know if you can see the edit history. At first I only added the `=` sign but then I figured I could add another class since he is actually asking for two different classes in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As posted, you aren't assigning anything to message (you're missing an `=` in the line `String message "sadsd: " + aaa + "\nfsdfds: " + bbb;`). I doubt that's the real problem, though, since that line wouldn't compile as is - what do you mean when you say the message isn't returned to main? Is the method returning null?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class Message{
    public String toString(){
       String message = "sadsd: " + aaa + "\nfsdfds: " + bbb;
       return message;
    }
}

public class MyClass{
     static Message message = new Message();
     public static void main(String[] args){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message.toString());
     }
}
```